# Listen to change events of multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to listen to the change event of multiple input elements of different types at the same time.

**This does not work:**

```
$(function(){
  $(".update_search").change( function() {
    alert("do some");
  });
});

<input class="update_search" id="car_type_ids_" name="car_type_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="1">
<select id="size" name="search[size]">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

The select and input tags are working fine, though I'm only receiving the change events on the check box.

**EDIT:**
I'm calling jQuery after the DOM was rendered. Thus all events should become bound.

Comment: are you include jQuery library?

Comment: Could you post rendered HTML instead?! Aren't you binding event before all elements are available in the DOM?

Comment: Alright, wait a second.

Comment: Some input controls only fire a change event when the focus moves away from the element.

Comment: Thanks, jfriend00, I'll try that out

Comment: try delegating event `$(document).on('change', '.update_search', function () {})`

Comment: There, it goes, feeling so dumb right now. There is no class in my select tag

Answer (score 5):

try this..

```
$(function () {
       $("#car_type_ids_,#size").change(function () {
           alert("do some");
       });
   });
```

Or you can do this as...

```
<input class="update_search" id="car_type_ids_" name="car_type_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="1">
<select id="size" name="search[size]" class="update_search">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="2">2</option>
</select>



$(function () {
       $(".update_search").change(function () {
           alert("do some");
       });
   });
```